# A Srivaishnavite teacher says Radha's story is in Bhagavatam, but not her name

Tags: bhagavata-purana, radha

In Tamil:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fva7PFb2bCs&t=3861s

What is the basis to say that?

1:08:20 - Krishna's footsteps are seen walking alongside a woman and the woman is said to be Radha.

Answer (score 0):

The claim, in my opinion doesn't sustains with evidence present in the Srimada Bhagvatam.

The Gaudiyas themselves claim that there's no direct mention of the deity of Radha in the Bahgvatam. Read more - [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14627/why-be-so-secretive-in-mentioning-devi-radharanis-name-in-srimad-bhagavatam)

The reason given is -

In the Purport to Srimada Bhagvatam [10.30.28](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/30/28/) Srila Prabhupada notes -

> Purport
>
> **Śrīla Viśvanātha Cakravartī explains that the word ārādhitaḥ refers to Śrīmatī Rādhārāṇī. He comments, “The sage Śukadeva Gosvāmī has
> tried with all endeavor to keep Her name hidden,** but now it
> automatically shines forth from the moon of his mouth. That he has
> spoken Her name is indeed Her mercy, and thus the word ārādhitaḥ is
> like the rumbling of a kettledrum sounded to announce Her great good
> fortune.”

---

So, with varied speculations some sects interpret the term "gopi" as referring to Radha. However, in the letter of the word, Radha is not mentioned and described in the Srimada Bhagvatam.

Rest all claims, maybe based on sectarian philosophies by the gurus of that sects. For layman, Radha and her story, unfortunately is not directly mentioned in the Bhagvatam.

The claim by the said teacher stands dubious and unverifiable, as per my analysis of the text.

Comment: Vivikta day before yesterday only i had this doubt i got it clarified by kattupadi krishna acharyas pravachaa, where in bhagavatam mention Nila devi is born as elder cousin of srikrishna, krishna first married Radha rani.  It was mentioned Nila. Nila = Radha Rani.  Radha rani was elder and she completed her avatar as Gopika and again to be born as Nila devi and marries krishna in the same birth.

Comment: @Vivikta Is it not Srimad Bhagavatam (as opposed to Srimada Bhagavatam)?

Comment: Yes, technically you're correct, iast transliterated. Yes. @AravindSuresh